# How to remove character inside element tag in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am formatting a registration form in WordPress. The last `p` element tag contains a `|`. This form cannot be edited directly. This is the current markup of the forgot password tag:

```
<p id="nav">
 |  <a href="?action=lostpassword">Forgot password?</a>
</p>
```

How can I remove the `|` inside the `#nav` so that the 'Forgot password?' link will remain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easy solution would be to just super simple replace the pipe char with nothing. ;)

```
$("#nav").html($("#nav").html().replace("|", ""));
```

---

**Edit:**
As discused (and mentioned by A. Wolff) in another answer, it is even a good idea to do this in a function, to prevent double DOM search of the `p#nav` element. You can do it like this:

```
$("#nav").html(function(i, html){
    return html.replace("|", "");
});
```

Comment: nav is an id not a class. So #nav should be used instead .nav

Comment: i think you should give credit to the update because it is answered in the same post

Answer (score 4):

If the textnode containing the `|` is always the first child of the `p` you can use `childNodes[0].remove()`, like this:

```
document.getElementById('nav').childNodes[0].remove();
```

Or in jQuery:

```
$('#nav').contents()[0].remove()
```

```js
document.getElementById('nav').childNodes[0].remove();
```

```html
<p id="nav">
  | <a href="?action=lostpassword">Forgot password?</a>
</p>
```

Comment: This is the best answer (imho...) because if any unobstrusive event handler is bound to anchor element, this answer preserves it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`.html( function )`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) to changing html of element. In function remove target character.

```js
$("#nav").html(function(i, html){
    return html.replace("|", "");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="nav">
 |  <a href="?action=lostpassword">Forgot password?</a>
</p>
```

Comment: Why would you use a function? Just unnecessary code, imo. Beside your code will now replace all pipes in every `p`. Use a better selector!

Comment: @eisbehr This is better than doing extra useless DOM request as in your answer, imho

Comment: The change now to the function parameter makes more sense to me. So okay, now I'm fine. @A.Wolff.